# Property closure can't see my singleton shared properties

Tags: swift, macos, singleton, closures

I decided to go with closures when getting a value of a property in my class, but this value depends on a singleton value (logged user name).

```
class BrokerTVC: NSViewController, DBTable {

@IBOutlet weak var table: NSTableView!

var mainRequest = { () -> String in
    switch LoggedUser.shared.type{
    case LoggedUser.shared.admin:
        return "select * from broker where approved = true"
    case LoggedUser.shared.client:
        return "select * from broker where approved = true and ..."
    default: return ""
    }
    return ""
}}

class LoggedUser{
    var type: Roles?
    var iD: String
    var username: String

    static let shared = LoggedUser()

    private init(){
        type = .admin
        iD = "(xx, xxxxxx)"
        username = "root"
}}
```

Somehow, this closure doesn't recognize the `shared` property of this singleton (**Value of type "LoggedUser" does not have "admin"**). Am I missing out on some core principles of how closures work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok with a closure.
It seems that `Roles` is an optional enum value - so you should do it this way.

```
var mainRequest = { () -> String in
    if let type = LoggedUser.shared.type {
        switch type {
            case .admin:
            case .client:
            default: return ""
        }
    }
    return ""
}}
```

Comment: The reason was because singleton property `type` was of an optional type, so I had to unwrap it in a `switch` statement